# Count of sessions exceeds pageviews when using measurement protocol for event reporting

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

We have created a server-side tracking for file downloads when users are simply getting a direct download link. We are passing an event collection to GA using Google analytics measurement protocol. Everything seemed fine, but we've noticed that the number sessions started to surpass the pageviews. After the investigation, we found that every time event is sent to GA using measurement protocol it also counts as a session. In the end of the day, it's like 100 sessions and 50 pageviews, which is absolutely wrong.

Any ideas how to solve this?..

A hit looks like this: `v=1&t=event&tid=UA-XXXXXX-X&cid=555&ec=File%20Download&ea=Download&el=Filename&dh=xxxxxxx.com`

Comment: For the pageview, do you mean the download page? Or is the download page hosted on some other domains?

Answer (score 0):

Add `ni=1` to make hits non-interactive.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ni.